# How to 'Refresh' MS Access Database in Login Form vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

[image]

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data

Public Class frmLoginBP
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Business_ProfileConnectionString)

    Private Sub lblInterfaceTypeTemp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        'Format the timer.
        lblDate.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")

    End Sub

    Private Sub lblDate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblDate.Click
        'Format the timer.
        lblDate.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmLoginBP_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Show initial panels when loading the program.
        Timer1.Enabled = True

        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Business_ProfileConnectionString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        'button Register
        frmRegistrationBP.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShowPassword(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click
        If txtBPPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = True Then
            txtBPPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = False
        Else
            txtBPPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If txtBPID.Text = "" Or txtBPPassword.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Enter Credentials", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error!")
        Else
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                connection.Open()
            End If
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count(*) from [Business Details] where Email=? and Password=?", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBPID.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBPPassword.Text
            Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

            If (count > 0) Then
                MsgBox("Login succeed!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                frmWelcomeNew.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Else
                MsgBox("Account not found. Check your credentials!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        txtBPID.Text = ""
        txtBPPassword.Text = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

First, I need to create an account in order to login into my system, thus, I press "Register" button. After I fill up the required textboxes,

[image]

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmRegistrationBP
    Dim pro As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim command As String
    Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub lblInterfaceTypeTemp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
        'Declare variable.
        Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog

        'Filter the file types.
        opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg;*.png)|* .jpg;*.png"

        If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

            'Assign the file to the picture box.
            pcbBusinessPhoto.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_BizRegisPG1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel_BizRegisPG1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_BizRegisPG1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset_BizRegisPG1.Click
        txtBizAddress.Text = ""
        txtBizAddress.Text = ""
        txtBizName.Text = ""
        txtBizPhoneNo.Text = ""
        txtPassword.Text = ""
        txtPasswordReenter.Text = ""
        txtSSM.Text = ""
        cboBizType.Text = ""
        pcbBusinessPhoto.Image = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtBizName_BizRegis_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBizName.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_BizRegisPG1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext_BizRegisPG1.Click

        If txtSQAnswer.Text = "" OrElse cboSQ.Text = "" OrElse txtSSM.Text = "" OrElse txtBizAddress.Text = "" OrElse txtBizEmail.Text = "" OrElse txtBizName.Text = "" OrElse txtBizPhoneNo.Text = "" OrElse txtPassword.Text = "" OrElse txtPasswordReenter.Text = "" OrElse cboBizType.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill in the textboxes!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        ElseIf txtPasswordReenter.Text <> txtPassword.Text Then
            MsgBox("Your Reentered Password is not the same!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Else
            If IsNumeric(txtBizPhoneNo.Text) = False Then
                MsgBox("Enter numeric value only in Company Phone Number", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
            ElseIf IsNothing(pcbBusinessPhoto.image) Then
                MsgBox("Please upload Business Photo", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
            Else
                pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\chiac\OneDrive\Desktop\OMC\Code\[OMC] Business Partner\[OMC] Business Partner\Business Profile.accdb"
                connstring = pro
                myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
                myconnection.Open()
                command = " insert into [Business Details] values (@SSM,@BizName,@Address,@Email,@HP,@BizType,@Password,@BusinessPhoto,@OHFrom,@OHTo,@SQ1,SQ1Answer)"

                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Command, myconnection)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@SSM", CType(UCase(txtSSM.Text), String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@BizName", CType(txtBizName.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Address", CType(txtBizAddress.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Email", CType(txtBizEmail.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@HP", CType(txtBizPhoneNo.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@BizType", CType(cboBizType.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Password", CType(txtPassword.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@BusinessPhoto", pcbBusinessPhoto.Image))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@OHFrom", CType(cboOHFrom.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@OHTo", CType(cboOHTo.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@SQ1", CType(cboSQ.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@DQ1Answer", CType(txtSQAnswer.Text, String)))
                MsgBox("Record Saved")

                Try
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    cmd.Dispose()
                    myconnection.Close()
                    txtSSM.Clear()
                    txtBizAddress.Clear()
                    txtBizEmail.Clear()
                    txtBizName.Clear()
                    txtBizPhoneNo.Clear()
                    txtPassword.Clear()
                    txtPasswordReenter.Clear()
                    cboBizType.Text = ""
                    cboOHFrom.Text = ""
                    cboOHTo.Text = ""
                    pcbBusinessPhoto.Image = Nothing
                Catch ex As Exception

                    MsgBox(ex.Message)

                End Try


                frmRegistration2.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmRegistrationBP_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmRegistration2

    Dim pro As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim command As String
    Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim finalGender As String
    Private Sub frmRegistration2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUploadIC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUploadIC.Click
        'Declare variable.
        Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog

        'Filter the file types.
        opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg;*.png)|* .jpg;*.png"

        If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

            'Assign the file to the picture box.
            pcbIC.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_BizRegisPG2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit_BizRegisPG2.Click

        If txtIC.Text = "" OrElse txtFirstName.Text = "" OrElse txtLastName.Text = "" OrElse txtEmail.Text = "" OrElse txtHP.Text = "" OrElse dtpDOB.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill in the textboxes!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Else
            If IsNumeric(txtIC.Text) = False Then
                MsgBox("Please insert numerical value in Identity Card Number!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
            ElseIf IsNothing(pcbIC.image) = True Then
                MsgBox("Please insert Owner Photo!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
            ElseIf rbtFemale.Checked = False And rbtMale.Checked = False Then
                MsgBox("Please select your gender!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
            ElseIf rbtAgree.Checked = False Then
                MsgBox("Please AGREE with Goodstopia Terms & Conditions!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
            Else

                If rbtMale.Checked = True Then
                    finalGender = "Male"
                End If

                If rbtFemale.Checked = True Then
                    finalGender = "Female"
                End If

                pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\chiac\OneDrive\Desktop\OMC\Code\[OMC] Business Partner\[OMC] Business Partner\Business Profile.accdb"
                connstring = pro
                myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
                myconnection.Open()
                command = " insert into [Owner Details] values (@IC,@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@HP,@DOB,@Gender,@ICPhoto)"

                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myconnection)

                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@IC", CType(UCase(txtIC.Text), String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@FirstName", CType(txtFirstName.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@LastName", CType(txtLastName.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Email", CType(txtEmail.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@HP", CType(txtHP.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@DOB", CType(dtpDOB.Text, String)))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Gender", finalGender))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ICPhoto", pcbIC.Image))
                MsgBox("Record Saved")

                Try
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    cmd.Dispose()
                    myconnection.Close()
                    txtIC.Clear()
                    txtFirstName.Clear()
                    txtLastName.Clear()
                    txtHP.Clear()
                    txtEmail.Clear()
                    rbtFemale.Checked = False
                    rbtMale.Checked = False
                    pcbIC.Image = Nothing
                Catch ex As Exception

                    MsgBox(ex.Message)

                End Try
            End If

            Me.Hide()
            frmLoginBP.Show()


        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub rbtAgreeTerms_BizRegis_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbtAgree.CheckedChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

I press 'Submit', my MS Access Login Database has captured all the data I typed.

[image]
After that, The login form will reappear again. However, even though I had saved the details in my Login DB. I still can't manage to Login into my system. My guess is that it's because the Database in the Login form has not 'refreshed' yet.

So my question is How do I 'refresh' the database in my login form?

Comment: If you post a question and it gets closed, DO NOT simply copy and paste the same question again. It was closed for a reason so, even if creating a duplicate was OK, you'd still need to address the reason the first one was closed. What you should do is address the reason in the existing question, editing it accordingly, and then requesting that it be reopened. If you can't be bothered to use this site properly, why would anyone feel inclined to help you?

Comment: Try keeping the question relevant to the problem.  to me looks like the issue is likely in frmLoginBP Button1_Click event, the query you are executing isn't returning expected results.  You're querying the db directly here so Refreshing the DB or form is completely irrelevant.  Maybe just give us the detail of what isn't meeting expectations

Comment: The code you provide should have a minimal, complete, and reproducible example of your problem. You certainly missed the boat on minimal. Remove extraneous methods.

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text, ever

Answer (score 1):

Connections use unmanaged resources which they release in their `Dispose` method. You must `Dispose` connections. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for us. Declare connections in the method where the are used, not at the `Class` level. Declare the connection string at the class level so it can be used in any method in the class.

Don't include empty `Sub`s in your question. The `Timer` and the date label have nothing to do with the question. Don't include these methods.

Enable your `Timer` at design time. It is pointless to create a local variable for a new connection in `Form.Load` and then let it fall out of scope before it is ever used. Remember, connections need to be disposed.

In the `btnShowPassword` method (which is strangely a picture box, why?) you can toggle a `Boolean` property in a single line.

In `Button1.Click` use `OrElse` to short circuit the `If`. It will stop evaluating expressions as soon as it finds a `True`.

Now to the database code. You will never need to check `ConnectionState` because it will be declared in the method in a `Using` block. Both the connection and the command are included in the `Using` block because commands need to be disposed too. Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execute...`

I am happy to see the use of `Parameters`. I used the actual parameter name in the `CommandText`. The question mark works fine but it easier to tie the parameters to the `ParametersCollection` when you can see names. Access only pays attention to the position but it makes it easier to read.

The vb specific `CInt` has been optimized in .net.

The first code block should look like this.

```
Private ConStr As String = My.Settings.Business_ProfileConnectionString   '"Your connection string"

Private Sub btnShowPassword(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click
    txtBPPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = Not txtBPPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If txtBPID.Text = "" OrElse txtBPPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter Credentials", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error!")
    Else
        Dim count As Integer
        Using connection As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count(*) from [Business Details] where Email=@1 and Password=@2", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBPID.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBPPassword.Text
            connection.Open()
            count = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
        If count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Login succeed!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            frmWelcomeNew.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("Account not found. Check your credentials!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In the second Form I am dividing up the code in `btnNext.Click` method.
It would be rare for a phone number to have no dashes or maybe ext. but I left it alone. I just got rid of the `IsNumeric` left over from vb6.

I am surprised that you are not using the settings that you used in the first form. This might be your problem.

You do not need to convert a `Text` property to a `String`. It is already a `String`.

```
Private ConStr As String = My.Settings.Business_ProfileConnectionString   '"Your connection string"

Private Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog
    opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg;*.png)|* .jpg;*.png"
    If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        pcbBusinessPhoto.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_BizRegisPG1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext_BizRegisPG1.Click
    If Not ValidateInput() Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Try
        InsertData()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    MsgBox("Record Saved")
    ClearForm()
    frmRegistration2.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Function ValidateInput() As Boolean
    If txtSQAnswer.Text = "" OrElse cboSQ.Text = "" OrElse txtSSM.Text = "" OrElse txtBizAddress.Text = "" OrElse txtBizEmail.Text = "" OrElse txtBizName.Text = "" OrElse txtBizPhoneNo.Text = "" OrElse txtPassword.Text = "" OrElse txtPasswordReenter.Text = "" OrElse cboBizType.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill in the textboxes!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Return False
    End If
    If txtPasswordReenter.Text <> txtPassword.Text Then
        MsgBox("Your Reentered Password is not the same!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Return False
    End If
    Dim Phone As Long
    If Not Long.TryParse(txtBizPhoneNo.Text, Phone) Then
        MsgBox("Enter numeric value only in Company Phone Number", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Return False
    End If
    If IsNothing(pcbBusinessPhoto.image) Then
        MsgBox("Please upload Business Photo", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Private Sub InsertData()
    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into [Business Details] values (@SSM,@BizName,@Address,@Email,@HP,@BizType,@Password,@BusinessPhoto,@OHFrom,@OHTo,@SQ1,SQ1Answer)", myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SSM", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSSM.Text.ToUpper
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BizName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBizName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBizAddress.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBizEmail.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HP", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBizPhoneNo.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BizType", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cboBizType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BusinessPhoto", OleDbType.LongVarBinary).Value = pcbBusinessPhoto.Image))
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OHFrom", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cboOHFrom.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OHTo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cboOHTo.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SQ1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cboSQ.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DQ1Answer", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSQAnswer.Text
        myconnection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub ClearForm()
    txtSSM.Clear()
    txtBizAddress.Clear()
    txtBizEmail.Clear()
    txtBizName.Clear()
    txtBizPhoneNo.Clear()
    txtPassword.Clear()
    txtPasswordReenter.Clear()
    cboBizType.Text = ""
    cboOHFrom.Text = ""
    cboOHTo.Text = ""
    pcbBusinessPhoto.Image = Nothing
End Sub
```

And for the third Form

```
Private ConStr As String = My.Settings.Business_ProfileConnectionString   '"Your connection string"

Private Sub btnSubmit_BizRegisPG2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit_BizRegisPG2.Click
    If Not ValidateInput() Then
        Return
    End If
    Try
        InsertOwner()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    ClearForm()
    MsgBox("Record Saved")
    Me.Hide()
    frmLoginBP.Show()
End Sub

Private Function ValidateInput() As Boolean
    If txtIC.Text = "" OrElse txtFirstName.Text = "" OrElse txtLastName.Text = "" OrElse txtEmail.Text = "" OrElse txtHP.Text = "" OrElse dtpDOB.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill in the textboxes!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Return False
    End If
    Dim IC As Integer
    If Not Integer.Parse(txtIC.Text, IC) Then
        MsgBox("Please insert numerical value in Identity Card Number!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Return False
    End If
    If pcbIC.image Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Please insert Owner Photo!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Return False
    End If
    If rbtFemale.Checked = False And rbtMale.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("Please select your gender!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Return False
    End If
    If rbtAgree.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("Please AGREE with Goodstopia Terms & Conditions!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Private Sub InsertOwner()
    Dim finalGender As String
    If rbtMale.Checked = True Then
        finalGender = "Male"
    Else
        finalGender = "Female"
    End If
    Dim Command = " insert into [Owner Details] values (@IC,@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@HP,@DOB,@Gender,@ICPhoto)"
    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(Command, myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = UCase(txtIC.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HP", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtHP.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dtpDOB.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = finalGender
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ICPhoto", OleDbType.LongVarBinary).Value = pcbIC.Image
        myconnection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub ClearForm()
    txtIC.Clear()
    txtFirstName.Clear()
    txtLastName.Clear()
    txtHP.Clear()
    txtEmail.Clear()
    rbtFemale.Checked = False
    rbtMale.Checked = False
    pcbIC.Image = Nothing
End Sub
```

One more thing. Passwords should **never** be stored as plain text. Look up salting and hashing.

Answer (score 0):

In your "register" method you explicitly put the connection string in code:

```
pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\chiac\OneDrive\Desktop\OMC\Code\[OMC] Business Partner\[OMC] Business Partner\Business Profile.accdb"
```

In your login function you get it out of settings:

```
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Business_ProfileConnectionString)
```

(You also have the same code on the last line of Form Load, which is useless and should be removed)

--

I strongly suspect that these two connection strings point at different databases - your code is writing to a database, and you're opening it in access and seeing the data, but the app is looking in a different DB

If the settings mention `|DataDirectory|` or no absolute path, then the situation will potentially be even more confusing for you - you have a DB on your desktop, you have a DB in your project folder and you have a DB in your bin folder. If you ever make an update/insert that uses the connectionstring from settings, then you're editing the DB in the bin folder, but this DB is overwritten with a new copy of the DB from the project folder every time the app starts, so your changes are lost. Of course, in a production setting this doesn't happen because there is no bin folder or compilation process; it is merely a developer convenience (as a dev you're supposed to e.g. add new tables to the DB in the project folder)

Make sure your app is consistently looking in the same DB for all its operations (make your insert code use Settings too)